# Disable invoice email notification in Opencart

Tags: email, notifications, opencart, invoice

I want to disable, on my opencart store, the email that my clients get when they make an order (the invoice) because my products dont have a fixed price and the price is discussed over the phone.

Comment: You mean, order email, that get the user who after purchased ?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i mean

Comment: Which version of OC you are using ?

Comment: im using opencart version 1.5.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `catalog->model->checkout->order.php` in order.php file there would be method named `confirm` on line no 159 in which method OC update the order status after completion of checkout process & send an email to user.

At the end of this method approx line no 567 or 568, you have to comment the send email function or

```
$mail->send();
```

make this line to comment like that

```
//$mail->send();
```

That's it now OC will not sent out any email to your customers.